# Issue with 'ResidualGraph' in FindMaximumFlow

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization

I try to get the residual graph of the flow

```
weithsToEdgesV={0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.2,0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8,0.2, 0.2,0.8};

testGrap = Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 8}, {2, 1}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {2, 8}, {3, 6}, {3, 8}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 8}, {5, 1}, {5, 6}, {5, 8}, {6, 2}, {6, 3}, {6, 5}, {6, 8}, {7, 1}, {7, 2}, {7, 3}, {7, 4}, {7, 5}, {7, 6}}];

FindMaximumFlow[testGrap, n + 1, n + 2, "ResidualGraph",EdgeCapacity -> weithsToEdgesV]
```

But I get the next result:

```
 FindMaximumFlow[testGrap, 7, 8, "ResidualGraph", 
 EdgeCapacity -> {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.2,0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8,0.2, 0.2,0.8}]]
```

How can I get the residual graph?

Comment: Please add a minimal example with concrete data.

Comment: I edit the question

Comment: Obviously, `"ResidualGraph"` is not implemented (bug?). Try `data = FindMaximumFlow[testGrap, 1, 2, "OptimumFlowData", 
   EdgeCapacity -> weithsToEdgesV];`. Maybe you can extract the necessay information from `AssociationMap[data, data["Properties"]];`... Btw. your source and target were not vertices of the graph.

Comment: @Henrik There are several properties that don't work for either FindMaximumFlow or for OptimumFlowData.  It's even clear from the documentation page: [if you look at the examples](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptimumFlowData.html), several of the outputs are just the same as the input.  I *have* already reported this through the feedback form of the doc page.  It's these things, and that they don't really get fixed, what blew the fuse for me when I wrote that complains on Wolfram Community.

Comment: @Szabolcs I know about your post on Wolfram Community and I second your stand point. I just try to get out as much as possible from the software that we have here. Maybe it is time for a complete new rewrite for a graph-like object (with less opaque properties! and resembling `Graph`'s API) from our side? The major algorithms could be tunneled trough IGraphM. This should not be a too big issue for pure graphs (things could be based on sparse adjacency matrices), but I cannot tell how an efficient data structure for multigraphs would look like...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, 'ResiudalGraph' not implemented. I will use 'FlowMatrix' to implement s-t min-cut